# What is uniformly addressable memory?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, operating-system

What is "uniformly addressable memory" ?

Comment: As funny as your comment is, it's really just as poor a fit for this site as the parent question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the wikipage about [NUMA (non-uniform memory access)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access).